# netcdf dimension variable interpretation

Tags: netcdf

I'm trying to understand if this is allowed by NetCDF standards. It does not make sence to me, but maybe there is a reason why it is not forbidden at library level. Ncdump:

```
netcdf tt {
dimensions:
    one = 2 ;
    two = 1 ;
variables:
    int64 one(two) ;
data:

 one = 1 ;
}
```

And code to produce this file in python:

```
from  netCDF4 import Dataset
rr=Dataset('tt.nc','w')
rr.createDimension('one',2)
rr.createDimension('two',1)
var1=rr.createVariable('one','i8',('two'))
var1[:]=1
rr.close()
```

Note the variable with the same name as dimension, but with a different dimension than itself?!

So two questions:

1. is this allowed by standard?
2. if not, should it be restricted by libraries?

Answer (score 2):

It's valid because the names of attributes, names of dimensions, and names of variables all exist in different namespaces.

Comment: Thanks, if the namespaces are intended to be independent and all interpretation of the variables is up to user, then fine. Just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

It's valid, but obviously makes for confusing code and output and would not be acceptable in a professional sense.  Though, note that single-dimension arrays that have the same name and size as the dimension they are assigned to are called "coordinate variables."

For example, you'll often see a variable named `latitude` that is 1D and has a dimension named `latitude`.  `ncks` or `ncdump` should reveal a `(CRD)` next to that variable display, indicating that it is indeed coordinated to the array of latitudes.

Comment: Thanks. I know the principle of coordinate variables, just wanted to check the ways it can go wrong. Can You confirm that "ncdump reveals (CRD) next to coordinate variable", I do not think I have seen this and just checked with my simple test file. Cannot check ncks at the moment.

Comment: You're right, `ncdump` is not revealing that information to me, but `ncks` does.  Sometimes coordinate variables are noted by `(CRD)` and other times with `(Coordinate is lat)`, for example.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at ncks.